# Spring formatting with Formatting from String to String and spring:eval does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am running a spring 4.0 mvc webapp and want to make use of the formater SPI with a IbanFormatter:

```
    public class IbanFormatter implements Formatter<String>
    {
        @Override
        public String print ( String iban, Locale locale )
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iban);
            for (int i = 4; i < sb.length(); i += 5)
            {
                sb.insert(i, ' ');
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String parse ( String iban, Locale locale ) throws ParseException
        {
            return iban.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        }
    }
```

Additionally I have a AnnotationFormaterFactory:

```
public final class IbanFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<IbanFormat>
{
    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter ( IbanFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType )
    {
        return new IbanFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser ( IbanFormat annotation, Class<?> fieldType )
    {
        return new IbanFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes ( )
    {
        HashSet<Class<?>> hashSet = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        hashSet.add(String.class);
        return hashSet;
    }
}
```

And an annotation of course:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IbanFormat
{}
```

With an Object annotated like this:

```
public class DirectDebitDTO 
{
    @IbanFormat
    private String  iban;
}
```

I registerd this formatter like this:

```
@Override
protected void addFormatters ( FormatterRegistry registry )
{
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new IsoFallbackJodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new IbanFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
}
```

My DateFormatter seen above works like a charm.

In my jsp I want to show the formatted iban:

```
IBAN: <spring:eval expression="directDebit.iban"  />
```

It does not work. It just shows unformatted iban. I debugged it and found the reason in line 65 in ExpressionUtils

```
public static <T> T convertTypedValue(EvaluationContext context, TypedValue typedValue, Class<T> targetType) {
    Object value = typedValue.getValue();
    if ((targetType == null) || (value != null && ClassUtils.isAssignableValue(targetType, value))) {
        return (T) value;
    }
    if (context != null) {
        return (T) context.getTypeConverter().convertValue(value, typedValue.getTypeDescriptor(), TypeDescriptor.valueOf(targetType));
    }
    throw new EvaluationException("Cannot convert value '" + value + "' to type '" + targetType.getName() + "'");
}
```

The first `if` statement is triggered because both values are Strings. No conversion and thus no formatting takes place. So it wouldn't even help to add a Converter

Of course I could change the type of iban from String to an Iban.class just to get type conversion.

For me it looks like a Bug, but havn't found anything about this.
Is this intended behaviour or a bug?

Comment: I would say it is an oversight (and you might want to [register an issue](http://jira.springsource.org) for that. As a workaround you could directly call your `conversionService` from the eval tag (it should work with a normal SpEL expression). Something like `@conversionService.convert(directDebit.iban, T(String))` should work. That would save you a custom type. Although creating a descriptive value type like IBAN isn't that bad imho (just like an `Email` or `Telephone` type, nicely expresses what it is and can enclose some functionlity).

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11215